# Dynamic order by multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

I use SQL Server 2012. I have a sample table named 'Table1' with seven columns.

```
        CREATE TABLE TABLE1 
            (
                Field1 INT , 
                Field2 INT , 
                Field3 INT , 
                Field4 INT , 
                Field5 INT , 
                Field6 INT , 
                Field7 INT 
            )
            GO

        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1,2,9,5,1,5,85)
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (2,6,8,4,1,4,45)
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (3,5,7,3,5,6,1)
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (4,4,6,1,51,4,1)
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (5,5,5,4,7,2,7)
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (6,5,4,6,4,7,8)
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (7,12,5,3,2,5,3)
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (8,1,6,5,9,5,1)
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (9,1,13,2,1,7,3)
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (10,6,9,3,6,2,6)
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (11,2,1,2,8,7,7)
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (12,7,6,1,3,3,2)
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (13,7,2,6,4,7,1)
        GO
```

I have created the below Stored Procedure, This SP is able to query data considering the asked order by column.
    I can query my table with each possibility of single column and kind of order by (ASC or Desc).

```
    CREATE Procedure ProceName
    (
        @OrderByField INT = 1,
        @OrderDirection INT = 0 -- 0 = Asc , 1 = Desc
    )  
    As  
    Begin  
        SELECT
                *  
        FROM Table1
        ORDER BY
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=0 AND @OrderByField=1 THEN Field1 END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=0 AND @OrderByField=2 THEN Field2 END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=0 AND @OrderByField=3 THEN Field3 END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=0 AND @OrderByField=4 THEN Field4 END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=0 AND @OrderByField=5 THEN Field5 END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=0 AND @OrderByField=6 THEN Field6 END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=0 AND @OrderByField=7 THEN Field7 END ASC,

                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=1 AND @OrderByField=1 THEN Field1 END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=1 AND @OrderByField=2 THEN Field2 END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=1 AND @OrderByField=3 THEN Field3 END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=1 AND @OrderByField=4 THEN Field4 END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=1 AND @OrderByField=5 THEN Field5 END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=1 AND @OrderByField=6 THEN Field6 END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @OrderDirection=1 AND @OrderByField=7 THEN Field7 END DESC        End  
    GO



EXECUTE ProceName  @OrderByField=1, @OrderDirection=0
EXECUTE ProceName  @OrderByField=6, @OrderDirection=1
```

Now I need to change this sp for accepting multi columns as order by series columns. They can be pass by name or by order of columns.
        In this case i should be able to execute my SP like below command:

```
    EXECUTE ProceName  @OrderByField='6,7,2', @OrderDirection='0,1,1'
```

How can I achive this gool **with out using the sp_executesql (Dynamic Query)?**

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/conditional-order-by and https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/sql-variant-use-case/

Answer (score 0):

Well, your ascending and descending wouldn't matter in your case unless you were trying to choose asc and desc for each column.  Here is using the last column.

```
DECLARE @OrderByField VARCHAR(64) = '1,3,7'

DECLARE @DynamicColumns VARCHAR(256) = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@OrderByField,1,'FIELD1'),2,'FIELD2'),3,'FIELD3'),4,'FIELD4'),5,'FIELD5'),6,'FIELD6'),7,'FIELD7')

DECLARE @OrderDirection INT = 1
DECLARE @order varchar(4)
SET @order = CASE WHEN @OrderDirection = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END

--uncomment this line of code to add the sort to every column which only matters for DESC since ASC is default
--SET @DynamicColumns = REPLACE(@DynamicColumns,',', ' ' + @order + ',')

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = (
        'SELECT
                *  
        FROM Table1
        ORDER BY ' + @DynamicColumns + ' ' + @order)

SELECT @sql

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: I think what the op try to achieve is specify order for each columnfield

Comment: @LONG well then there would have to be a lot more parameters, one for each column....

Comment: yes... that will be complicated even for simple input

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE Procedure ProceName
    (
        @OrderByField VARCHAR(100),
        @OrderDirection VARCHAR(100),

    )  
    As  
    Begin  

    Declare @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

    if OBJECT_ID('Example1') is not null
    begin
    drop table Example
    end

    if OBJECT_ID('Example2') is not null
    begin
    drop table Example2
    end

    Create table Example1
    (
    id int identity(1,1),
    Field varchar(20)
    )

    Create table Example2
    (
    id int identity(1,1),
    OrderNumber varchar(10)
    )

    --iterate each element for both @OrderByField and @OrderDirection
    Declare @separator char(1)=','
    Declare @position int = 0
    Declare @name varchar(20)
    Set @OrderByField = @OrderByField + @separator 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
         /*iterate each for @OrderByField */
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    While CHARINDEX (@separator,@OrderByField,@position) != 0 
    BEGIN

    SET @name = SUBSTRING (@OrderByField,@position,CHARINDEX (@separator,@OrderByField,@position)-@position)

    SET @SQL = 'Insert into Example1([Field]) Values(' + char(39) + @name + char(39) + ')'
    EXEC(@SQL)

    SET @position = CHARINDEX(@separator,@OrderByField,@position)+1

    END


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
         /*iterate each for @OrderDirection */
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SET @position = 0 --do not forget to reset the position number

    Set @OrderDirection = @OrderDirection + @separator

    While CHARINDEX (@separator,@OrderDirection,@position) != 0 
    BEGIN

    SET @name = SUBSTRING (@OrderDirection,@position,CHARINDEX (@separator,@OrderDirection,@position)-@position)

    SET @SQL = 'Insert into Example2([OrderNumber]) Values(' + char(39) + @name + char(39)+ ')'
    EXEC(@SQL)

    SET @position = CHARINDEX(@separator,@OrderDirection,@position)+1

    END




Set @name = '' --reset the @name for the use of Cursor
declare @NewName varchar(500) =''


Declare row_cursor CURSOR
FOR
select 'Field'+a.Field + ' '+ case when b.OrderNumber = 0 then 'ASC' else 'DESC' end +',' as command
from Example1 as a 
inner join Example2 as b
on b.id = a.id


OPEN row_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM row_cursor into @name

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS =0)
begin
Set @NewName = @NewName + @name

FETCH NEXT FROM row_cursor into @name
end
close row_cursor
deallocate row_cursor

SET @NewName = REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(@NewName),1,1,''))


SET @SQL = 'Select * From Table1 Order by ' + @NewName

--Print(@SQL)
EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

Comment: the logic is create two tables for storing the two input data, use `CHARINDEX` to store each element from the input for each;  select data from joined results to generate each pair using table cursor, then use dynamic sql to get the final result

Comment: I have been looking the way in which we don't use Dynamic Query. (How can I achive this gool with out using the sp_executesql (Dynamic Query)?)